# String conversion of uint8_t not being recognized in java

Tags: java, arduino, type-conversion

So I have a java server running that is expecting data from a client in my arduino. The original type of my data is uint8_t, but i want it as a String. 
This is how I'm doing my conversion:

```
String stringData = (char*) data;
```

where 'data' is an array of type uint8_t.
I can print the 'stringData' value and it looks exactly how I want it, but when it gets to my java server it shows up as a little question mark inside of a box. Does anyone know why?

P.S. It works just fine when create a normal string (String stringdata = "123456") So I'm assuming it has to do with the conversion.

Here's the code that pertains:

Arduino:

```
void arduinoClient(String accountID) {
  if (client.connect(ip, 9876)) {
    client.println(accountID);
    Serial.println("Message sent");
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}
```

Java:

```
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (socket.getInputStream()));       
String message = buff.readLine();
```

I'd also be fine with doing the conversion on the java side if it is more convenient (or possible) to do so

Comment: Please specify the type of `data`, and where you get the `String` type from, and give an example of typical `data`.

Comment: 'data' is an array of type uint8_t. I don't know what you mean by "where you get the String type from". 'data' is initialized by reading an NFC tag

Comment: Do you know the character set and encoding of `data`? (Or, are you going to punt with "platform default"?)

Comment: `data` gets it's value as so: `memcpy(data, (const uint8_t[]){ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 3, 1 }, sizeof data);` if that's what you're asking

Comment: @dks209: That doesn't look very zero-terminated to me. Also, these values are usually not graphical characters. In particular, ASCII 7 is the bel character that on output to a terminal produces a sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue has to do with what uint8_t really is.  When you convert it to a char* you're changing it to the [ACII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the number, not the actually character that represents the number.  [This thread explains how to do the conversion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448168/conversion-of-uint8-t-to-a-string-c)  The question mark is Java trying to print an ASCII value that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that, but i'm having some issues getting it to work. I tried both options listed there. It may be my inexperience with C that is the real issue. I get an error from the first code listed and binary numbers from the second. There was an error with the 'malloc' lines so i had to cast it using `static_cast<char *>(malloc( buffer_size ));` I don't know if that caused a problem or not. Is there no simpler way?

Comment: I think that's the simplest way, using bit shifting is really the best way to get single digits out of binary numbers.  What error are you getting?

Comment: `error: cannot convert 'uint8_t (*)[16] {aka unsigned char (*)[16]}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '1' to 'char* convert(uint8_t*)'` Which occurs when i try to call the function (this pertains to the first answer's posted code in that thread) `char *theString;
              theString = convert(&data);`

Comment: I believe it's because you are trying to convert an array. Which is a pointer to a series of uint8_t variables. You should try looping through the array and converting it number by number to a char*.

Comment: I printed it out in a for loop with this `Serial.print(convert(&data[i]));` so i can see what it's returning, and what i'm getting is a binary representation of the numbers contained in `data`

Comment: Could it be that you're using serial.print and not printf("%s", convert(&data))?

Comment: It looks like printf() is not a function in arduino, although after following some steps here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf I added it and tried as you said, using `Serial.printf("%s", convert(&data[i]));` in a for loop, but it is still printing in binary

Comment: Are you sure it's not a string that represents the binary number?

Comment: Right you are! My bad! I created a String in the for loop `message += convert(&data[i]);` and that gave me a string representation of the number i'm wanting in binary, and My java server can understand that. So i'll worry about converting the binary back to a number on that side. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

see this code:

`byte buf[31];
String myString = "MD111111111111111111111111111111111#(40)'";
uint8_t data[] = myString.StringToCharArray(buf,30);`

by this code we can convert String to uint_8 
in your case you must do:

`String stringData = (char*) data;
byte buf[256];
uint_8 result = stringOut.StringToCharArray(buf,256);`

Comment: Thanks, but i'm actually trying to do it the other way around, convert uint_8 to String