# Function taking void pointer as argument and returning void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, void-pointers

I have written a code in C in which I have defined a function which takes void* as its argument and also returns void*. I am getting few warnings and `Segmentation Fault` during execution. 
Please let me know if I am doing something silly. I am somewhat new to all these.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *fun1(void *a) {
    int temp = *((int*)a);             // Typecasting the received void* valud dereferencing it.
    temp++;
    return ((void*)temp);               // Returing the value after typecasting.
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int a =5;
    int *p = &a;
    int b = *p;

    printf("%d %d",a,b);

    int x = *((int*)fun1((void*)&b));     /*
                                             Here I am trying to send "b" to "fun1" function after doing a typecast.
                                             Once a value is receievd from "fun1" , I am typecasting it to int*.
                                             Then I am deferencing the whole thing to get the value in int format.
                                         */
    printf("\n%d",x);

    return 0;
}
```

O/P:

```
main.c:8:13: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]                                                               
Hello World                                                                                                                                                
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From GDB debugger, I found that the segmentation fault is occurring at the line 20 after the value is returned from `fun1()`. I suspect that the way I am sending the value b to `fun1()` is wrong.

Also, why the intermediate `printf` statement in line 18 `printf("%d %d",a,b);` isn't executing?

Comment: `return ((void*)temp);` you are casting an `int` to a `pointer`.

Comment: Your problem is in `fun1()`. Try to understand what you're actually returning from the function. Grab a pen and some paper if you have to. As for your `printf` - add a `\n` at the end.

Comment: The return value from the function is `5`, treated as a pointer.  Addresses in the first page of memory are usually invalid; you can neither read from nor write to them.  So the program crashes because you have an invalid pointer that you dereference.  If you changed `int x = *((int*)fun1((void*)&b));` to `int x = (int)fun1(&b));`, you probably wouldn't crash.  The cast to `void *` is unnecessary; any object pointer will be converted to `void *` when required by the function prototype.  (Function pointers are a different matter; they needn't be the same size as other pointer types.)

Answer (score 2):

On line `return ((void*)temp);`
You are casting an `int temp` to a `void*`

Note that taking the address of `temp` is also invalid because you will get the warning `warning: function returns address of local variable`

You could change the funtion to return an `int`

```
int fun1(void *a) {
    int temp = *((int*)a);             
    temp++;
    return temp; // <-- Return the int value instead of a pointer.
}
```

And then change the calling function to

```
int x = fun1(&b); // <-- since fun1 now returns an integer there is no need to cast it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You dereference a non-pointer value.  This is the [report](https://cee.studio/2020-02-28.t543ETlMJjN5eVlE/funptr).  I copied the error message as the follow.

=========== Start of #0 stensal runtime message ===========

Runtime error: **[dereferencing a non-pointer]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
-
- Reading 4 bytes from an illegit address (0x6).
-
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the read.
- [0]  file:/prog.c::23, 20
- [1]  [libc-start-main]
-
```

============ End of #0 stensal runtime message ============

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @mschuurmans for pointing out that the problem lies within the return type of fun1().
I have modified it now and it works.

```
    void *fun1(void *a) {
    int temp = *((int*)a);
    temp++;
    int *p = &temp;
    return ((void*)p);
    }
```

Comment: That's wrong as well. You're now returning [the address of a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380758/error-function-returns-address-of-local-variable).

Comment: @dragosht Yeah you are right. I shouldn't return a pointer that points to a local address. But somehow, I am not getting any errors or warnings while executing this. The o/p is as desired. Strange.