# array return type

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 30

void push(char );


char stack[MAX];
int tos=0;

int main(){
    char str[]="Arijit Saha";
    char *final;
    final=(char *)rev(str);
    printf("%s",final);
    rev(str);
    getch();
    return 1;
}

char* rev(char s[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        push(s[i]);
    char reverse[strlen(s)];

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        reverse[i]=pop();

    return reverse;

}

void push(char c){
    stack[tos]=c;
    tos++;
}
int pop(){
    tos--;
    return stack[tos+1];

}
```

These are the error messages..

```
Compiler: Default compiler
    Executing  gcc.exe...
    gcc.exe "C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c" -o "C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.exe"   -g3  -I"C:\TC\INCLUDE"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.4-Q16\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" -L"C:\TC\LIB" -L"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.4-Q16\lib" -g3 
    C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c:20: error: conflicting types for 'rev'
    C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c:14: error: previous implicit declaration of 'rev' was here

    C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c: In function `rev':
    C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c:28: warning: function returns address of local variable

    Execution terminated
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable, that's what going wrong. http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx5.html

Comment: That is an excellent compiler warning.  Please respect it!

Comment: were you asked to reverse a string only using a LIFO? Because otherwise this is an overkill...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Warning: Function returns address of local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897914/c-warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable)

Comment: 1). you dint prototype rev and 2). returning a local variable 3). not a problem but why do u cast the return value of char * in main. everything there is char *.

Answer (score 3):

`c:14: error: previous implicit declaration of 'rev' was here`

Your error is because you didn't generate a prototype for `rev()` before you used it in your `main()`. Either move your function above main or add a prototype.

`c28: warning: function returns address of local variable`

Your warning is because you are trying to return the address of a local variable, you can't do that. Local variables are out of scope when you leave the function, so you need to do something else (such as use a dynamic array via adding `malloc()`/`free()` calls)

Answer (score 0):

`char reverse[strlen(s)];` is on the stack. After the function complete it is now invalid, but you are returning its address.

Answer (score 0):

A variable which has *automatic* storage duration doesn't exist anymore in the calling function. Accessing to it leads to an undefined behavior (anything can happen). Here you are returning `reverse` from `rev`, which is a local variable.

Rather allocate the memory dynamically:

```
int *reverse = malloc(strlen(s)); /* + 1 for '\0' character ? */
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse is a local array. It is destroyed, when the function exits, but you return a pointer to its contents. Ideally, you should return the array by having a parameter that the function will load data into, i.e.

```
void MyFuncReturnsArray(int* myArr, int n)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      myArr[i] = i;
}
```

Instead of

```
int* MyFuncReturnsArray()
{
     int myArr[10];
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        myArr[i] = i;
     return myArr

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
char* rev(char s[]) {
    char reverse[strlen(s)];
    ...
    return reverse;
}
```

`reverse` is an temporary array with automatic storage duration that is being deallocated once the execution leaves the scope of this function. You return a pointer that becomes a *dangling pointer*.
Trying access the memory that this pointer points to produces **undefined behavior**.

Apart from the fact that you should allocate it dynamically by using `malloc`, note that `strlen` returns the length of the string, you will also need the space for the terminating character (`'\0'`). You should create `reverse` like this:

```
char* reverse = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
```

and don't forget to assign `'\0'` to the last character of `reverse`. Also don't forget that the caller of this function becomes responsible for deallocating the memory that has been allocated by `malloc`, i.e. the caller should call `free` on the returned pointer.