# char return error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 30

void push(char );


char stack[MAX];
int tos=0;

int main(){
    char str[]="Arijit Saha";
   // char *final;
   //   final=(char *)rev(str);
   //   printf("%s",final);
    rev(str);
    getch();
    return 1;
}

int rev(char s[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    push(s[i]);
    char reverse[strlen(s)];
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<strlen(s);j++)
    reverse[j]=pop();
    printf("%s",reverse);
    return 1;

}

void push(char c){
     stack[tos]=c;
     tos++;
     }
char pop(){
    tos--;
    return stack[tos+1];

}
```

Errors: C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c:38: error: conflicting types for 'pop'
C:\TC\BIN\stringrevusingstack.c:28: error: previous implicit declaration of 'pop' was here

Here I am returning char and saving that returned char in char variable ( reverse[i] ).. Then why this error?

Comment: I answered that in your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228270/array-return-type) Please read the answers to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the function pop() has not been declared by the time the call to pop is first encountered. To fix this, either define a function prototype or switch up the position of the definitions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 30

char stack[MAX];
int tos=0;

void push(char c)
{
    stack[tos]=c;
    tos++;
}
char pop()
{
    tos--;
    return stack[tos+1]; 
}

int rev(char s[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        push(s[i]);
    char reverse[strlen(s)];
    for(int j=0;j<strlen(s);j++)
        reverse[j]=pop();
    printf("%s",reverse);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="Arijit Saha";
    //char *final;
    //final=(char *)rev(str);
    //printf("%s",final);
    rev(str);
    getch();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

define a function prototype for `pop`. That'll work

The error you are getting is because the compiler's confused about the function `pop` 's definition and declaration. Make it a good habit to declare a prototype before you use it.

And if you again see this type of error, be sure it is it!

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you get these errors is that your functions lack [*prototypes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype). Either move all functions to before their first point of use (i.e. before `main` function), or provide prototypes for them:

```
int rev(char s[]);
void push(char c);
char pop();
```

In the absence of prototypes, C compiler decides that your `pop()` function returns `int`, the default return type of functions lacking a prototype. Once the compiler discovers that `char` is the actual return type of `pop`, an error is issued.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `pop()` before having at least declared it. You have to declare it before using it, at least.

Before main add:

```
char pop(); //declaration
```

Answer (score 0):

Either define the function before you use it or provide a declaration (prototype) for the "pop" function as you have done with "push":

```c
void push(char);
char pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
char pop(void);
```

after the defines.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have to declare the function before using it. So, either you need to put the pop (and push) functions before rev; or you need a couple of lines up top:

```
void push(char);
char pop();
```

Also, I suspect that the return line of pop should be

```
return stack[tos];
```