# Multidimensional Char Array return error from a C function

Tags: c, arrays

I have such a function in C:

```
char **collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize)
{
    printf("Collecting character distribution...\n");
    long x;
    char distribution[256][2] = {0};

    for (x = 0; x < lSize; x++)
    {
            distribution[(int)buffer[x]][0] = (char) buffer[x];
            distribution[(int)buffer[x]][1]++;
    }
    return (char **) distribution;
}
```

I need to return two dimensional distribution array from the function above. And my main function is as the following:

```
int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    long lSize;
    struct Bar result = funct();
    char **distribution;
    buffer = result.x;
    lSize = result.y;
    distribution = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize);
    printf("%s\n", distribution);
    //struct Bar encoding_tree = generate_encoding_tree(distribution);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

> warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897914/c-warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable

Comment: you have created a variable inside a loop and you are trying to pass its address outside, that makes no sense as the variable would be destroyed as soon as it loses scope

Comment: @Arc676: interesting case - while that duplicate concerns *exactly the same message* (and the OP did not see it or did not look for it), I find myself questioning if the accepted answer is advisable in general. It does not even answer the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a variable that is declared locally in the function. What you should do is declare the variable you want to store results in in the scope where you need these results. Then you pass a pointer to this variable into the function to write to. Something along these lines:

```
void collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize, char distribution[256][2])
{
        printf("Collecting character distribution...\n");
        long x;

        for (x = 0; x < 256; x++)
        {
            distribution[(int)x][0] = (char) x;
        }

        for (x = 0; x < lSize; x++)
        {

            distribution[(int)buffer[x]][1]++;
        }

}

int main()
{
        char *buffer;
        long lSize;
        struct Bar result = funct();
        char distribution[256][2] = {0};
        buffer = result.x;
        lSize = result.y;
        collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize, distribution);
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
            printf("%c: %d\n", distribution[i][0], distribution[i][1]);
        }
        //struct Bar encoding_tree = generate_encoding_tree(distribution);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Marco, could you edit your answer? Now I get error on printf function inside main class.

Comment: Hey yusuf, there are several other bugs in your code which will throw errors, which are separete from your original question. For example, you need to actually allocate `distribution`, and you can't print a two-dimensional char array with `printf` like that; you will need to loop through the strings in your array. I edited my code to reflect what I mean, but I didn't try compiling or debugging.

Comment: It's hard to say where that is coming from without seeing your full code and trying to narrow down where the segfault is being thrown. I would suggest accepting one of the answers here and opening a new question if you don't manage to debug it.

Comment: Marco, I put all the code which are needed. There is any bugs on other parts.

Comment: @MarcoTompitak  @yusuf  In `main` declare `distribution` as `char ** distribution` . In your code you access index out of bound thus UB.

Comment: Found one problem, I edited my code, like this it works for me.

Comment: It works, but doesn't give the same output. It gives a very weird output.

Comment: What you're printing is probably not what you want. Guessing from your code, you probably want something like `a: 1, b:4` etc.? I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because that array is a local variable, and you are passing it outside its scope.

You need to use dynamic allocation for this

```
char **array = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));
int i;
for(i=0; i != 20; ++i) {
    array[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Now you can easily return `array`

---

**EDIT 1**

All you have to do is change

```
char distribution[256][2];
```

this to

```
char **array = malloc(20 * sizeof(char *));
int i;
for(i=0; i != 20; ++i) {
    array[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));

}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

To print the strings, you should a loop

```
for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    printf("%s\n", distribution[i]);
```

Comment: Haris, could you present your answer fully?

Comment: @yusuf check if you can understand now

Comment: Haris, now I get this error on main function: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: @yusuf offcourse, you have a `2D array` of `char` now. You need a loop to print all the `strings` in that.

Comment: @yusuf, try the changes i have made

Answer (score 1):

Its simple messages your funtion `return`'s a local variable . Your array does not exist outside function block .

Inside your function you can do this -

```
char **distribution;
distribution=malloc(256*sizeof(char *));
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    distribution[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(distribution[0][0]));
```

Also in `main` , this -

```
printf("%s\n", distribution);
```

`distribution` is of type `char **` , you can't pass it to `%s` specifier .

You can do it in  loop -

```
for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
   printf("%s\n", distribution[i]);
```

### Edit-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char **collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize);
int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    long lSize;
    struct Bar result = funct();
    char **distribution;
    buffer = result.x;
    lSize = result.y;
    distribution = collect_character_distribution(buffer, lSize);      
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
        printf("%s\n", distribution[i]);
    //struct Bar encoding_tree = generate_encoding_tree(distribution);
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
          free(distribution[i]);
    free(distribution);
    return 0;
}

char **collect_character_distribution(char *buffer, long lSize)
{
        printf("Collecting character distribution...\n");
        long x;
        char **distribution;
        distribution=malloc(256*sizeof(char *));
        for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            distribution[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(distribution[0][0]));
        for (x = 0; x < lSize; x++)
        {
                distribution[(int)buffer[x]][0] =  buffer[x];
                distribution[(int)buffer[x]][1]++;
        }
    return distribution;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote . Please leave a comment .

Comment: I have upvoted you ameyCU :) Could you explain your answer briefly?

Comment: @Yusuf array you declare in function is a local variable , it cannot be accessed outside the function , when you do so , compiler issues a warning. For that ,we declare a `char **` and allocate memory to it , so it retains it's values even after fucntions termination .

Comment: ameyCU, could you please present your answer fully?

Comment: ameyCU, there is a problem on this line: for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            (*distribution)[i]=malloc(20*sizeof(distribution[0][0]));

Comment: @Yusuf ohh , yes , Either write `*(distribution+i)` there or `distribution[i]`. Sorry that went past , I made correction in code also .

Comment: @Jongware I dont think that i explained that error message, 1 line explanation was that and required (IMHO) ,but yes fix that  I provided had a little mislead during typing , and had a flaw which when pointed out corrected it.  But Thanks for your response !! :-) Will remember it next time .

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `char **distribution` as a parameter and in your function use:

```
distribution = new char*[256];
distribution[0] = new char[2];
distribution[1] = new char[2];
```

Then you don't need to return `distribution` array from your function. The problem is local variables are destroyed after their scope ends and in your case `distribution` exists only in function `collect_character_distribution`.

Comment: Ardavel, could you present your answer fully?