# Allocating memory for a struct variable using a function

Tags: c, linux, database, malloc

As part of a larger project, I am trying to write a function that will allocate enough memory for a struct variable and assign values to its member variables after scanning them from the keyboard. In other words, I am trying to create a sort of a constructor function. The reason for this is because I think that's the best way to create a database-like program in c, where all the student_t variables will be stored in a student_t* array called classroom.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 10
#define STRLIM 50

typedef struct student{
char* name;
int age;
}student_t;


student_t* init_student(student_t* s);

int i=0;//its the array counter
student_t* classroom[N];

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

while(i<N){
  //  classroom[i]=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    init_student(classroom[i]);
    classroom[i]->age=i;
    printf("The age of student #%d is : %d \n",i,classroom[i]->age);
    printf("the name of student #%d is : %s",i,classroom[i]->name);
    i++;
}

    printf("the size of the classroom is : %ld",sizeof(classroom));
    return 0;
}//end of main()

student_t* init_student(student_t* s){
    s=(student_t*)malloc(sizeof(student_t));
    s->name=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLIM);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(s->name,STRLIM,stdin);

    return s;
}
```

Gdb ouput shown in the attached image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flXBU.png).

Please check out my [repo](https://github.com/gtsompanoglou/cdata).
I am guessing something about my build and datatypes is off .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware, POSIX considers `typedef`s ending in `_t` to be standard, and `student_t` definitely isn't. I see no reason to unnecessarily `typedef` this `struct` anyway. As for the issue at hand, I think `s=(student_t*)malloc(sizeof(student_t));` will change the local variable only. You might need to use `student_t **` as the parameter.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Or use the returned value: `classroom[i] = init_student();`

Comment: I'd recommend to keep object allocation and user input separated.

Comment: Also `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior still... why do teachers keep teaching it...

Comment: you were all pretty much right and your suggestions really helped me especially @mediocrevegetable1. After all of that, I figured out that I was worried about the wrong thing since the very first moment and my code had a much bigger problem. If you are reading this , don't malloc and return, it's just asking for trouble! [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897914/c-warning-function-returns-address-of-local-variable)

Comment: I am now dealling wiht  REALLY unexpected realloc issues, which won't let me assign the new allocated block to the previous one without replacing every value of the array with the last keyboard input, but that is another story. Thank you all for your help and interest.